# Reliability of a single-pass deniable authentication protocol?

Tags: elliptic-curves, protocol-design, authentication, discrete-logarithm, zero-knowledge-proofs

I look for one-pass deniable authentication protocol with a short message payload for my project and find a solution:

```
*Wei-Bin Lee, Chia Chun Wu, and Woei-Jiunn Tsaur. "A novel deniable authentication protocol using generalized ElGamal signature scheme." Inf. Sci.-177(6):1376-1381 (2007)*
```

Unfortunately later I found a forum archive where member claimed to have discovered an attack on this protocol:

http://bbs.pediy.com/showthread.php?t=91904

But in another modern works authors mention this protocol as a reliable: eprint.iacr.org/2013/783

I am not a specialist in mathematics and I can not assess the credibility of proofs.
I put the found materials for download:
http://torfone.org/download/Q-A.doc   (and `nida.pdf` for protocol description)

This protocol is still secure? Will it work correctly on the EC25519?